# Heroku, Rails: WildCard SSL cause env['warden'] to return nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, devise, warden

In my rails app. I'm using devise. Users will enter the top page from several subdomains like "ja.myapp.com", "www.myapp.com" etc..
I use several subdomains only inside promotion pages, so when they enter the "sign in" page, All of them will redirect to the "www" subdomain page.

When user sign in, if the user's profile_type was "Student", user will redirect to "Students' home"., if it was "Teacher", "Teachers' home".

Everything works fine when I test with "POW", but when I uploaded it to the production server.
After user signed in, all of them will redirect to the TOP page.

I rollback the app and, try signing in again, but same thing happend
This happened after I uploaded the heroku certs from "single domain SSL" to "wildcard subdomains SSL".

After I change the SSL to single domain one, this won't happens anymore inside the rollbacked site.

I suppose that this happened because of the "wildcard subdomain SSL" & devise session controller, but not so sure about that.

Does anyone have any idea to fix this problem?

Below are the code.

## routes.rb

```
root :to => 'students#index', :constraints => lambda { |request| request.env['warden'].user.try(:profile_type) == 'Student' }
root :to => 'teachers#index', :constraints => lambda { |request| request.env['warden'].user.try(:profile_type) == 'Teacher' }
root :to => 'pages#home'
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "sessions", :registrations => "registrations", :confirmations => "confirmations"}
```

## config/initializers/session_store.rb

```
MyAPP::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_app_secure_session', domain: :all

# coding: utf-8
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  after_filter :clear_sign_signout_flash
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    url = root_path
  end

  def new
    @title = I18n.t "sessions.new.title"
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  def destroy
    super
  end

  protected
  def clear_sign_signout_flash
    if flash.keys.include?(:notice)
      flash.delete(:notice)
    end
  end

end
```

## application_controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :set_locale, :www_redirect

  private
  def www_redirect
    #if Rails.env.production
      parsed_subdomain = request.subdomains.first
      locale = Locale.find_by_subdomain(parsed_subdomain)
      if (use_www? && parsed_subdomain != "www") || locale.nil?
        redirect_to request.url.sub(parsed_subdomain, "www")
      end
    #end
  end

  def use_www?
    true
  end

  def set_locale
    if user_signed_in? 
      if current_user.profile_type == "Teacher"
        I18n.locale = I18n.default_locale
      else
        I18n.locale = current_user.locale.i18n_form.to_sym
      end
    else
      if request.subdomains.first == "www" && cookies[:locale]
        I18n.locale = cookies[:locale].to_sym
      else
        I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_subdomain || I18n.default_locale
        cookies[:locale] = {
          value: I18n.locale.to_s,
          expires: 1.year.from_now,
          domain: :all
        }
      end
    end
  end

  def extract_locale_from_subdomain
    parsed_subdomain = request.subdomains.first
    locale = Locale.find_by_subdomain(parsed_subdomain)
    if locale
      I18n.available_locales.include?(locale.i18n_form.to_sym) ? locale.i18n_form.to_sym : nil
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

## locale_settings_controller.rb

```
class LocaleSettingsController < ApplicationController

  def switch_language
    locale = params[:locale]
    locale = "www" if locale == "en"
    path = params[:uri]
    cookies[:locale] = {
      value: locale,
      expires: 1.year.from_now,
      domain: :all
    }
    if Rails.env.production?
      base_url = "http://" + "#{locale}" + ".myapp.com"
    else
      base_url = "http://" + "#{locale}" + ".myapp.dev"
    end
    url = path == "/" ?  base_url : base_url + "#{path}"
    redirect_to url
  end
end
```

## production.rb

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

## config/initializers/rack_rewrite.rb

```
require 'rack/rewrite'

LingualBox::Application.config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Lock, Rack::Rewrite) do
  r301 %r{.*}, 'http://www.myapp.com$&', :if => Proc.new {|rack_env|
    rack_env['SERVER_NAME'] == 'myapp.com'
  }
end if Rails.env == 'production'
```